# My sessions aren't working correctly

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

```
                   <?php 
                    if($_SESSION['loggedin']){
                     echo '<li id="login-btn"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
                   }
                   else{
                     echo '<li id="login-btn"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
                   }
                   ?>
```

This is inside of the HTML for my Navbar. I want it to where if they are logged in, it will show "Logout", if they aren't logged in, it'll show "Login", (self explanatory)

I have this in my login.php

```
 $loggedin = "";
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

For some reason, no matter what I do, my navbar keeps displaying "Login"? Help please, thank you!

Comment: where is the session_start();

Comment: testing 123........................

Comment: Top of every php page I got.

Answer (score 1):

Session are global variables in [php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)...

> Session variables are not passed individually to each new page,
>   instead they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning
>   of each page (session_start()).

if you want to access it on different page... you have to add

```
<?php
         session_start();
?>
```

at the begining .... even in your *login.php* page

Comment: It is on my login.